# Reputation graph column lists posts from previous day

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-history

Why when I go to reputation graph and click on column representing day I see list of posts which affected reputation but **from previous day**?

Example: I selected September 25 but listed posts are from September 24.

I am able to reproduce this in newest version of Chrome, FireFox, Opera. I am using Windows 7 Ultimate SP1.

[image]

---

**Way around** for people who posts affected reputation today and can't click that freaking area on graph (since it doesn't exist yet):

***don't forget about these two options***:

[image]

for instance if we pick `time` instead of `graph` we can see:

[image]

Comment: @Kendra Yes, that seems to be duplicate. There is also one in uber-meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259692/reputation-for-graph-is-off-by-a-day. Anyway I will leave this post for now to show that problem still exists.